# Пуш уведомления не корректно работают, как решить?

Tags: php, ios, laravel, push-уведомления

Пуш уведомления Apns приходят с задержкой 1 - 5мин, php 7, laravel, используется очередь beanstalkd. В логах очередь обрабатывается быстро, но пуш приходит очень долго, бывыет и не приходит вовсе. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У меня такой-же вопросю Вы решили проблему?